# How to cache in spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc, caching

I use cache in spring mvc.But since 
the server reset 2 times a day ,
the cached data will be destroyed . 
How should the cached data is stored in
a folder that this does not happen ?

Comment: I think you should not call it a "folder" but try to find a caching solution that is independent, like this: http://code.google.com/p/simple-spring-memcached/

Comment: teşekkürler Seyfülislam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you dont want to persist data on secondary storage since that will then involve disk IO and will again reduce your application's performance.

All you need is to store data in a distributed cache. A distributed cache will have dedicated servers for caching, so that even if you server resets/restarts, data will remain cached.

There are number of distributed caching solutions that provide integration with spring mvc like memcached being one of them. [TayzGrid](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/) (an in-memory distributed datagrid) also provides integration with spring mvc. You can easily [configure it as caching provider](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/spring-integration.html). And your same application will start using distributed cache without any code change required.

Comment: You should seriously consider Couchbase - it has roots from Memcached - but its persistent and compatible with memcached protocol. See http://www.couchbase.com